# Inherit form or add type to each form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, silex, symfony-2.4

I am searching for an easy way to add a bundle of fields to each form.

I have found a way to extend the *AbstractType* and use the `buildForm` method to add more fields.
When creating the form I give the name of my new type ([How to Create a Custom Form Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html)).

In my opinion it is an easy way, but it is restricted to one type per form.

Is there a better way to achieve anything like that?
I have read the cookbook of symfony, but I have only found stuff how to extend an existing form not how to create an own form "template" with my fields.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have you tried using inheritance?

This is really simple, first you have to define a form type:

```php
# file: Your\Bundle\Form\BaseType.php
<?php

namespace Your\Bundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class BaseType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text');

        $builder->add('add', 'submit');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Your\Bundle\Entity\YourEntity',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'base';
    }
}
```

Then you can `extend` this form type:

```php
# file: Your\Bundle\Form\ExtendType.php
<?php

namespace Your\Bundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ExtendType extends BaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        # you can also remove an element from the parent form type
        # $builder->remove('some_field');

        $builder->add('number', 'integer');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Your\Bundle\Entity\YourEntity',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'extend';
    }
}
```

The `BaseType` will display a *name* field and an *add* submit button. The `ExtendType` will display a *name* field, an *add* submit button and a *number* field.

Comment: If you extended `BaseType` with `ExtendType` as you are now then you would overwrite the parent `buildForm` with the child. To extend it properly you would need to include `parent::buildForm($builder, $options)` at the start of the child `buildForm`.

Comment: You did it in the wrong one. `Abstract Type` has an empty buildForm so rebuilding that in `BaseType` would be pointless. You need to use the `parent::buildForm(etc)` in the `ExtendType` so that it also uses the buildForm in the `BaseType`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's fixed.

Comment: When I asked I wasn't really sure about the form system and its behavior. Seems to be easier than I thought/understand.

Comment: But it seems it isn't possible to add an extension to the base type via *AbstractTypeExtension*.

Comment: I'M not sure that I understand your question. `AbstractTypeExtension` is a class from Symfony2, you want to extend it?

Comment: Oh didn't seen that you already answered. I meant I want to register an extension for the BaseType which I extend.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this with the getParent() function.

```
<?php

namespace Your\Bundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;


class ChildType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // $builder->remove('field');
        // $builder->add('field);
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return ParentType::class;
    }
}
```