# how to pass the same options to all fields of a Symfony2 form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a symfony form that looks like this and I need to pass the same options to every field.

- I need to set `label` to `true` because I am using [elaotranslationformbundle](https://packagist.org/packages/elao/form-translation-bundle) not globally, only for some forms.
- I need to have the same class on all fields because I am using bootstrap.
- I need to pass the translation_domain to each field based on an option on my form (which means I cannot do it in the `setDefaultOptions` method.

How can I avoid the following repetitive code ?

```
$defaultOptions = array(
    'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
    'label' => true,
    'translation_domain' => (
        $options['professional']?
        'prospect_form_librarian' :
        'prospect_form_user'
    )
);
$builder
    ->add('name', null, $defaultOptions + array('some_other_option' => 42))
    ->add('city', null, $defaultOptions)
    ->add('contactEmail', 'email', $defaultOptions)
    ->add('zipCode', null, $defaultOptions)
    ;
```

I would like to have the code look like this :

```
$defaultOptions = array(
    'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
    'label' => true,
    'translation_domain' => (
        $options['professional']?
        'prospect_form_librarian' :
        'prospect_form_user'
    )
);
$builder->someMethodCallThatWouldSolveMyProblem($defaultOptions)
$builder
    ->add('name', null, array('some_other_option' => 42))
    ->add('city')
    ->add('contactEmail', 'email', $defaultOptions)
    ->add('zipCode')
    ;
```

Comment: How about using the form types that come with the bundle you're using, or creating your own form type accordingly? [see the repo](https://github.com/Elao/ElaoFormTranslationBundle/tree/master/Form/Extension): `$resolver->setDefault('label', true);` is what you're after. Extend one of those form types (or create your own), and add `'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']` to the defaults wherever you need them. Then write `$builder->add('name', 'yourFormType');` like you normally would

Comment: So you're saying that you want to avoid having that $defaultOptions array defined in every form type?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem : I still want to be able to use different types like 'text', 'email', 'password'. Creating another type per type is not a very good option I think.

Comment: Can you use inheritance to solve this? Create a base form than all other form types inherit from it. Like this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414166/inherit-form-or-add-type-to-each-form

Comment: @gnarly : no, that won't do, because php does not have multiple inheritance, and I need to be able to still use, for instance, the `ChoiceType`

Comment: @greg0ire OK. I guess I don't understand the question. Good luck.

Comment: I want to be able to use for instance the 'email' and 'choice' types. These types share options. I want to be able to pass the same default options to both types. I would like to make some method call, and then able to just write `->add('name', null, array('some_option' => 42))->add('city')->add('contactEmail', 'email')` and get the same result

Comment: @greg0ire: That's where you're wrong. Check the source of the bundle (and check the symfony2 cookbook). All form types extend from the `form` parent type. Sure PHP doesn't have multiple inheritance, but that doesn't stop you from inheriting from a class that inherits from another class (5 levels of inheritance is quite common, really). Look at the choice type defined by the bundle you're using, for example... creating custom types _is_ the answer to your problem, it really is

Comment: Is it possible to create custom builder?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem 5 levels of inheritance is maybe common, [but does not look like a good practice](https://ocramius.github.io/blog/when-to-declare-classes-final/). Now let's admit I should create custom types. I will have to create one class per built-in type I want to use ('email', 'choice', you name it), inherit from a base class, and write a `getParent` method that returns the type ('email', 'choice'). I'm talking about `getParent` because obviously, the base class cannot inherit from `EmailType` and `ChoiceType` and `PasswordType`, can it ? Doesn't all this look a bit heavy ?

Comment: @Marek: a custom builder might be a good idea…

Comment: Well if you don't want to use inheritance and still be able to share a functionality between your FormTypes you might be interested in the Traits: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php (you must be running PHP 5.4 at least)