# Forms in Symfony 2: 'inherit_data' or class inheritance?

Tags: forms, symfony, inheritance, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

I need to make a bunch of forms in Symfony 2.8 using inheritance. I've seen two approaches being used:

1. Using 'regular' class inheritance like described [in the first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414166/inherit-form-or-add-type-to-each-form).
2. Using [`inherit_data`](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/inherit_data_option.html).

What's the difference between the two? Why would I pick one over the other?

Also, can I just make my 'base'-form type an abstract class, in order to prevent it from being used in its own? Are there any downsides to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly speaking all needed info is already disclosed in links  you posted.

Form inheritance is about real OOP class inheritance.
inherit_data is used for composition approach, so you can use it in forms, which are not really so bounded logically to be inherited from base class.

This implements composition over inheritance approach
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance