# Class does not implement "Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface" in Sylius

Tags: symfony, sylius

We are trying to extend from `CustomerProfileType` and we are getting error like:

```
 {
"code": 500,
"message": "Could not load type "abc\Form\Extension\AdminApi\CustomerProfileTypeExtension": class does not implement "Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface"."
}
```

Customer.yml:

```
sylius_admin_api_customer_create:
    path: /
    methods: [POST]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.customer:createAction
        _sylius:
            serialization_version: $version
            serialization_groups: [Detailed]
            form:
                type: abc\Form\Extension\AdminApi\CustomerProfileTypeExtension
```

CustomerProfileTypeExtension.php

```
final class CustomerProfileTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        // Adding new fields works just like in the parent form type.
        $builder->add('contactHours', TextType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'app.form.customer.contact_hours',
        ]);

        // To remove a field from a form simply call ->remove(`fieldName`).
        $builder->remove('gender');

        // You can change the label by adding again the same field with a changed `label` parameter.
        $builder->add('lastName', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'app.form.customer.surname',
        ]);
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getExtendedType(): string
    {
        return CustomerProfileType::class;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 12):

Are you calling createForm method by passing your entity ?

If so then you might forget to insert the formType class you created for the entity. This is where i was doing mistake.

in my case i wrote `$form = $this->createForm(Article::class);`

but the code should be `$form = $this->createForm(ArticleFormType::class);`

Answer (score 5):

As the exception message suggests, you are implementing a form type extension instead of a form type.

Form type extensions [are intended to modify the way forms function](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html):

> They have 2 main use-cases:
>
> You want to add a specific feature to a single form type (such as adding a "download" feature to the FileType field type);
>
> You want to add a generic feature to several types (such as adding a "help" text to every "input text"-like type).

To implement specific forms, you should either implement the `Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface` or extend a class that implements it (commonly in Symfony that would be `Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType`).

To use inheritance in form types, use [`FormInterface#getParent`](https://api.symfony.com/4.1/Symfony/Component/Form/FormInterface.html#method_getParent). [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414166/inherit-form-or-add-type-to-each-form) might help you with that.